# G++ "does not name a type"

Tags: c++, global

```
struct MyStruct {
  int x;
};

MyStruct theVar;

theVar.x = 10;

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

Why is the compiler giving me the error:

> error: ‘theVar’ does not name a type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only create variables and initialize them outside `main` at the global scope. You cannot assign to variables at global scope like that.

You have two options:

**Initialize it at time of creation:**

```
MyStruct theVar = {10};
```

Or

**Assign it in `main`:**

```
theVar.x = 10;
```

Note that first approach is better as it just has one step, **Initialization**, Second has two steps **Initialization** and **Assignment**.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do an assignment like that outside a function. Move it inside of main, or make it an initialization:

```
MyStruct theVar = {10};
```